# Search by first letters of the word

Tags: javascript, html, search, render

I'm writing a search for an audio player. There was a problem: nothing is rendered on the screen, but there are no errors in the console.

```js
var songs = [{
    url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Redfoo_-_New_Thang.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Redfoo',
      song: 'New Thang'
    }
  },
  {
    url: 'http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpoc6cHNDP1r0jthjo1.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Hugo',
      song: '99 Problems'
    }
  }
];

search = () => {
  var names, song, allForSeach;
  var input = this.textInput.value;
  songs.forEach(function(item) {
    names = item.artist.name;
    song = item.artist.song;
    allForSearch = names.concat(song);
  });

  function init() {
    let template = `<td><a href=#>%name</a></td>`,
      search = document.querySelector('.search'),
      tr = document.querySelector('.mess-hide'),
      render = a => tr.innerHTML = a.map(e => template.replace('%name', e)).join(`\n`);

    search.addEventListener('.search', function(e) {
      let value = input.toLowerCase();

      render(allForSearch.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().startsWith(value)));
    });
    render(allForSearch);
  }
}
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #EAEDEF;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
<button className={searchClass} onClick={this.search} title="Search">click</button>

<table className="table">
  <tr className="mess-hide">

  </tr>
</table>
```

I will explain a little: `songs` an array of objects. Using `forEach`, I copy all the names and names in another array in order to organize the search. But for some reason, nothing appears in the browser. Why can this be so?

Comment: There are too many mistakes.

1) no event handler attached to button

2)search and init will never run.

3)this.state?

Comment: @ShishirArora and how i can fix it?